# IOS get position

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, position

I have a lot of button inside a UIScrollView and i am trying to get their position on button click. Here is my code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 0, 262, 748)];
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(262, 816);
scrollView.bounces=NO;
scrollView.delaysContentTouches=YES;

buton1 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
buton1.frame = CGRectMake(2, 0, 262, 102);
buton1.bounds = CGRectMake(2, 0, 262.0, 102.0);
[buton1 setTag:1];
[buton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left_gride.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [scrollView addSubview:buton1];
```

and

```
-(void) buttonClick:(UIButton*)button{
if ([button tag]==1)
{
     NSLog(@"position:%d",buton1.frame.origin.x);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"position:%d",buton2.frame.origin.y);
}
```

}

What is wrong with my code.Thanks.

I also tried with :

```
-(void) buttonClick:(UIButton*)button{
if ([button tag]==1)
{
     NSLog(@"position:%d",buton1.frame.origin.x);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"position:%d",buton2.frame.origin.y);
}

-(void) buttonClick:(UIButton*)button{
if ([button tag]==1)
{
     NSLog(@"position:%d",button.frame.origin.x);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"position:%d",button2.frame.origin.y);
}
```

But i just get the same.Position 0;

Comment: Please write what you expected and what happened if you execute this code.

Comment: I expected to return the position and all i get is position 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The only thing - you use wrong format specifier in NSLog. As coordinates are floating point numbers you should use `%f` instead of `%d`:

```
NSLog(@"position:%f",buton1.frame.origin.x);
```

Comment: Now i have another problem. Even if i scroll the buttons the position doesn't change.Why is that.

Comment: because button position is in coordinate space of scrollview's contents - so it actually does not change when you scroll. If you want to get screen coordinates you need to convert to them (e.g. using convertPoint:toView: method)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` method, there is a trick because the documentation says : This method scrolls the content view so that the area defined by rect is just visible inside the scroll view. If the area is already visible, the method does nothing.

Try to scroll to `CGRectMake(buton1.frame.origin.x, buton1.frame.origin.y, yourScrollView.frame.width, yourScrollView.frame.height)`.

You can use a fudge factor on 3rd parameters.