# How to programatically get position of an object from the storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard

Say if I have a button on the storyboard - how do I get its position programatically from the storyboard? I would like to have a sample in Objective C.

Comment: Seek for example in Google. Not here.

Comment: But some people have asked similar questions on StackOverflow

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431103/ios-get-position and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319642/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-position-of-a-ui-button-iphone

Comment: @Raptor Quite ironic Raptor, I could say the same, why do you put your questions here too? I am sorry but that is just plain rude.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, this is a duplicate. When I searched though, those questions did not pop up probably because my keywords were different.

Comment: @VideoGamingIOs -- its K man, posted before search in google , 1000 answer in stack overflow comes under for your question

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I swear I am not lying!

Comment: @VideoGamingIOs - k my friend , I am not say you are lier, sometimes it happening for everyone, me also faced just like problem,

Comment: NO codes, no help. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Raptor I have made two apps, and I am new to objective C. They are submitted to Apple store and have only been downloaded 10,000 times

Comment: I mean what have you tried in your issue, not your "achievement". At least you have to show some attempted codes, right?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to connect an outlet (IBOutlet).

After that, each UIView or subclass of it (UIButton is UIView) has a frame property.

```
myButton.frame.origin.y;
myButton.frame.origin.x;
```

In order to get it's position.